# Using Git on windows in a development / production environment

Tags: git, windows-7, development-environment, production-environment

This is what I'm trying to figure out.

I'm familiar with having a "Development" and separate "Production" working folders for a code base.

With Git however you can just have a "Production" environment and create a branch of it to work on. The problem I have is that I need the contents of the "Production" folder to be access while working on it.

What I'm looking for is to have a "Development" and "Production" folder on Windows network. All work is done on the "Development" folder then pushed to the "Production" folder. However right now when I have this set-up and view the contents of the "Production" folder the files don't appear in there just the standard git-init files?

For example: "Test.txt" existing in "Development" and "Production" folders. I want to keep the "Production" version live. I edit the "Development" version of "text.txt" and then push the changes to "Production" which over writes the change in "Production", when I go to the "Production" folder I then can open "text.txt" and see all changes.

Right now however when I push changes the file does not appear in "Production" just the standard "GIT-init" files that are created. How do I resolve this where files exist it both location and can push changes from one location to another all on a windows network?

Comment: Are you trying to work directly in the directory that contains the live version of your site? Usually the best practice is to have a development instance that you can work on (and break, either deliberately or accidentally) that is fully separate from your production environment. Generally these are on physically separate machines, e.g. with the development environment on your laptop and the production environment on a proper server.

Comment: @Chris It's not a site just a code base. It does not need to be on server be say, just backed up. I would like to have a "Development" folder where all work is done, and then is pushed to a separate folder on the network for "Production" I tried using the push function but as mentioned it only seems to have the "Git-init" files and does not contain the actual files.

Comment: Ah, you're pushing to a bare repository. What you're seeing is normal. What version of Git are you using (check with `git --version`)? If it's new enough there might be a good alternative to get the behaviour you're after.